# Ajax Timer control in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have the code for the ajax timer as follows.. As the time becomes 0 the page will be redirected to another page.

```
<h3><asp:Label ID="timer" runat="server" Text="You will be redirected to the Authentication Page in..."></asp:Label>
<asp:Timer id="asptimer" runat="server"></asp:Timer>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" ></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="5"></asp:Label>
```

The c# code is

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        asptimer.Enabled = true;
        asptimer.Interval = 1000;
        asptimer.Tick += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(asptimer_tick);
    }

    protected void asptimer_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = (Convert.ToInt16(Label1.Text));
        i = i - 1;
        Label1.Text = i.ToString();
        if (i < 0)
        {
            asptimer.Enabled = false;
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }
    }
```

Now.. i want to hide the delay of page redirection using this timer. That is as the timer is executing , simultaneously the page must also redirect . Or the delay in redirection must be shown by this timer. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do here. But, I will implement this using a client side timer. See the code below:

WebForm1.aspx

```
        function LoadTimer() {
            var timeInterval = '<%= timeinterval %>';            
            var remainingSeconds = (timeInterval / 1000);
            var timeInterval = setInterval(function () {                                
                document.getElementById('divRemainingTime').innerHTML = "You will be redirected to the webform2 in... " + --remainingSeconds;

                if (remainingSeconds <= 0) {
                    window.location.href = "Webform2.aspx";
                    clearInterval(timeInterval);
                }
            }, 1000);
        }


<body onload="LoadTimer();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">             
        <div id="divRemainingTime"  runat="server"></div>        
    </form>
</body>
```

WebForm1.aspx.cs

```
public int timeinterval = 5000;
```